# Sorting strings via stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I am doing a coding exercise where I take the the raw data from a csv file and I print it in order of lowest to highest ranked literacy rates.

For example:

Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, female (%),United Republic of Tanzania,2015,76.08978

Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, female (%),Zimbabwe,2015,85.28513

Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, male (%),Honduras,2014,87.39595

Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, male (%),Honduras,2015,88.32135

Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, male (%),Angola,2014,82.15105

Turns into:

Niger (2015), female, 11.01572

Mali (2015), female, 22.19578

Guinea (2015), female, 22.87104

Afghanistan (2015), female, 23.87385

Central African Republic (2015), female, 24.35549

My code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LiteracyComparison {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        

        List<String> literacy = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get("literacy.csv"))) {
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                String row = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] line = row.split(",");
                line[2] = line[2].trim().substring(0, line[2].length() - 5);
                line[3] = line[3].trim(); 
                line[4] = line[4].trim();
                line[5] = line[5].trim();
                
                String l = line[3] + " (" + line[4] + "), " + line[2] + ", " + line[5];
                literacy.add(l);

            }
        }
        // right about where I get lost
        literacy.stream().sorted();
    }
}
```

Now I have converted the raw data into the correct format, it's just I am lost on how to sort it.
I am also wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this via the streams method. Please and thank you.

Comment: Think of each value in the `row.split(",")` array as a column, or field. Design a data structure (a class in this case) that stores each of those fields, and create of `List` for that data structure. Then sorting a `List<CustomDataStructure>` by the value of one of the columns, the literacy number in particular, should be very straightforward.

Comment: OK I made the class Literacy and added a new object into the arrayList via literacy.add(new Literacy(line[3], Integer.valueOf(line[4]), line[2], Double.valueOf(line[5]))); Yet I am still confused on how to sort the the rates via the stream method? Any hints?

Comment: You don’t sort a list via stream. A Stream operation never modifies the source. You can use `literacy.sort(comparator);` to sort the list. `literacy.stream().sorted();` only produces a sorted stream, not affecting the source list, but subsequent stream operations, if you chain some. As long as you don’t chain a terminal operation, the stream doesn’t do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I took a few liberties while refactoring your code, but the idea is the same. This could be further improved but it is not intended to be a perfect solution, just something to answer your question and put you on the right track.

The main idea here is to create a nested class called `LiteracyData`, which stores the summary you had before as a `String`. However, we also want to store the literacy rate so we have something to sort by. Then you can use a Java `Comparator` to define your own method for comparing custom classes, in this case `LiteracyData`. Finally, tie it all together by calling the `sort` function on your `List`, while passing in the custom `Comparator` as an argument. That will sort your list. You can then print it to view the results.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class LiteracyComparison {
    
    // Define a class that stores your data
    public class LiteracyData {
        private String summary;
        private float rate;
        
        public LiteracyData(String summary, float rate) {
            super();
            this.summary = summary;
            this.rate = rate;
        }
        
    }
    
    // This is a custom Comparator we defined for sorting LiteracyData 
    public class LiteracySorter implements Comparator<LiteracyData> 
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(LiteracyData d1, LiteracyData d2) {
            
            return Float.compare(d1.rate, d2.rate);
        }
    }
    
    public void run() {
        List<LiteracyData> literacy = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get("literacy.csv"))) {
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                String row = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] line = row.split(",");
                line[2] = line[2].trim().substring(0, line[2].length() - 5);
                line[3] = line[3].trim(); 
                line[4] = line[4].trim();
                line[5] = line[5].trim();
                
                String l = line[3] + " (" + line[4] + "), " + line[2] + ", " + line[5];
                
                LiteracyData data = new LiteracyData(l, Float.parseFloat(line[5]));
                literacy.add(data);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        // Sort the list using your custom LiteracyData comparator
        literacy.sort(new LiteracySorter());
        
        // Iterate through the list and print each item to ensure it is sorted
        for(LiteracyData data : literacy) {
            System.out.println(data.summary);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        LiteracyComparison comparison = new LiteracyComparison();
        comparison.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to create a class like `LiteracySorter`. You can achieve the same by replacing `new LiteracySorter()` with `(d1,d2) -> Float.compare(d1.rate, d2.rate)` or `Comparator.comparingDouble(d -> d.rate)`.